# Xamain.iOS doesn't has CFUUIDRef class?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms.

I want to create UUID.
But I can't find any c# version of 'CFUUIDXXXX'.

Anyone knows what the class name is?

If it doesn't exist, I have a question.
Looking Xamarin's API document is fastest way to know whether it exist or not?
If it doesn't exist, It seems like that Xamarin.iOS doesn't inject all the class from iOS native class?
Is it correct?

I also know about Guid. But I was told that there is no guarantee it's unique.

And also there is "UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor".
Is it good enough to use as UUID?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSUUID`(in Xamarin `NSUuid`) instead.

> This is the new younger cousin to CFUUID. NSUUID just popped up in iOS 6. It is pretty much exactly the same as CFUUID except it has a nice, modern Objective-C interface.

Here is a good comparison of all Id-Types: https://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/

Comment: Thanks Sven. Looking Api document is best way to check if Native code is available on Xamarin?

Comment: Normally, everything that is possible natively, shoud be possible with Xamarin. It's one of their selling propositions ^^ So I usually just start typing :) Your case is very rare. You have to ask Xamarin, why this is an internal class. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/master/src/CoreBluetooth/GuidWrapper.cs

Comment: Oh, Yes. Everything should be possible. My question was how can I know if there is native-injection class already prepared by Xamarin.

Comment: Just start typing :> If it doesn't exist, search the docs and/or github. If you can't find anything, search on bugzilla. If you can't find anything open a bug/issue :D